# Version control when creating a page or post with

Tags: workflow

I would love to know what is your workflow when creating new post or pages.

Do you edit the html and css of your pages and posts in local dev environment and push it to the production site?

What is your method?

I am asking this because I want to add version control to my workflow.

Any link or hint is appreachiated.

Comment: Why would you need to edit HTML and CSS files every time you create a post in WordPress?

Comment: Think about custom landing pages.

Comment: Wouldn't a Page Builder be easier to manage than custom HTML/CSS?

Comment: To a degree maybe. It is just hard to replicate a page while clicking through all the options. Easier would be to do it in html and css it think.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to have custom HTML per post is probably by using [post type templates](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/03/post-type-templates-in-4-7/). You can easily put those into version control.

As for the CSS, you could create separate files per post as well. But this harder to maintain and leads to more stylesheets that need to be downloaded by the user when they browse your site. I'd usually put all the different styles into one CSS file. This way, the browser only needs to download it once and then it will be cached.